# Issue with SSL generation on the newest expo-cli when doing yarn run on a project bootstrapped by npx create-react-native-app

Tags: react-native

https://github.com/expo/create-react-native-app

This issue has been closed, but why? I have no idea what's expected of me to do. What are the solutions, because I can't run the app on a web browser and I need to do this in order to develop, because my computer is slow.

I am using the latest version of react-cli and bootstrapped the app with npx create-react-native-app. I am using Windows and git bash, maybe the issue is related to those two. Also, it's telling me to enter a password, but there's no such thing as a root password on Windows. What can I do? Do I have to downgrade my expo-cli? How do you do so on Windows? What commands should I enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 expo start --no-https
```

allows us to avoid the issue of having to use ssl and thereby bypassing the issue with expo-cli on Windows.